# What is the "t" in i.landsat.toar

Tags: grass-gis, landsat

I'm using GrassGis 7.0.0 for Landsat imagery. In the description of [i.Landsat.toar](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass65/manuals/i.landsat.toar.html) under dos3 and dos4 is:

TAUz = exp[-t/sin(e)]

What is "t"? I cannot find any description about what it is. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

The GRASS GIS Landsat.toar module relies heavily on the [article by Chavez from 1996](http://info.asprs.org/publications/pers/96journal/september/1996_sep_1025-1036.pdf) and you ought to read that for a full understanding on what happens.

The implementation in GRASS GIS doesn't directly match the one seen in the paper, but I expect that this is a result of an aversion to the use of the trig-function 'sec' in GRASS GIS.

'TAUz' is *the atmospheric transmittance along the path from the sun to the ground surface*.

't' is referred to as 'del' in the original paper - where it is described as  '*the optical thickness values measured in-situ at the given wavelength*'

I would expect that GRASS GIS takes look-up-table values for this, based on standard atmospheres, selected based on location and time of year, but I will have to look into this to be certain.